# What is the significance of having a tangent bundle that splits into the direct sum of line bundles?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

We know that if the tangent bundle $TM$ of a manifold $M$ is trivial then $M$ is parallelizable. Is there some similar notion for manifolds whose tangent bundle splits into the direct sum of line bundles? I was just wondering why we would study such manifolds; what "good" things can we say about $M$ if we know that $TM$ splits? I hope this question is not too vague.

Comment: "I was just wondering why we would study such manifolds." Do you have any examples where people have studied such manifolds?

Comment: One context where I have seen this is when a vector bundle over a toric variety splits as a sum of line bundles then its projectivization is a toric variety.

Comment: Then $M$ has a finite covering which is parallelizable.

Comment: @Moishe Cohen Could you give me a proof of this result or a reference for the same?

Comment: Well, if you have a nontrivial real line bundle $L\to M$ (with connected $M$), there is a canonical 2-fold cover $M'\to M$ such that $L$ lifts to a trivial bundle $L'\to M'$. (The proof is the same as for the existence of the orientation cover of a non-orientable manifold.) Now, induct on the rank of $TM$.